# Quarkus Kafka Consumer throws SRMSG00207: Some components are not connected to either downstream consumers or upstream producers: on startup

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I am fairly new to Quarkus and Kafka and I have the following scenario.

I am writing a consumer to listen to a few topics (they are logging topics that log the various stages a quarkus message is going through in our systems eg: I log a msg once a message has been sent to the main kafka topic. Then every consumer for that message also logs a message to the logging topic once they read/successfully process that message). Not really relevant, but just for context.

I have in the past successfully written consumers in Quarkus that consume 2 or more topics successfully, but now this one is trowing the following message on startup.

```
2024-03-18 13:55:45,720 WARN  [io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.provider] (Quarkus Main Thread) SRMSG00208: The connector 'IncomingConnector{channel:'curr-in', attribute:'mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in'}' has no downstreams
2024-03-18 13:55:45,723 WARN  [io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.provider] (Quarkus Main Thread) SRMSG00207: Some components are not connected to either downstream consumers or upstream producers:
        - IncomingConnector{channel:'curr-in', attribute:'mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in'} has no downstream
        - IncomingConnector{channel:'stud-in', attribute:'mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in'} has no downstream
```

And then does not consume records from either topic.

My application.properties file looks as follows:

```
## Kafka student log properties
mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in.topic=academia-student-logging-topic
mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in.key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in.health-enabled=true
mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in.health-readiness-enabled=true
mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in.auto.offset.reset=earliest
mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in.enable.auto.commit=false
mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in.max.poll.records=1
mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in.client.id=KafkaLogConsumer
mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in.retry=true
mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in.retry-attempts=-1
mp.messaging.incoming.stud-in.retry-max-wait=20

## Kafka curriculum log properties
mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in.topic=academia-curriculum-logging-topic
mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in.key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in.health-enabled=true
mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in.health-readiness-enabled=true
mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in.auto.offset.reset=earliest
mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in.enable.auto.commit=false
mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in.max.poll.records=1
mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in.client.id=KafkaLogConsumer
mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in.retry=true
mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in.retry-attempts=-1
mp.messaging.incoming.curr-in.retry-max-wait=20
```

and my code looks as follows:

```
@Incoming("stud-in")
  @Incoming("curr-in")
  @Retry(delay = 120, delayUnit = ChronoUnit.SECONDS, maxRetries = -1, maxDuration = 300, durationUnit = ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
  public void receive(ConsumerRecord<String, String> event) throws Exception {
```

Strangely enough if I take out one of the topics, it happily consumes the data, but the moment I put in 2 @Incoming tags it bombs out. And its quite frustraint as I have quite a few WORKING examples of this and I can't for the life of me spot any difference.

My pom looks as follows just for completeness sake:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sun.kafka.readers</groupId>
<artifactId>integration-kafka-loglistener</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.16.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</surefire-plugin.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you describe happens if the configuration is there but no matching annotations are found.

The reactive messaging annotations (@Incoming, @Outgoing etc.) are not picked if not used directly in a CDI bean. So this may happen if channel annotations are used inside a class inherited by a CDI bean.

Comment: Hi @Ozan Günalp I'm not sure I understand. I have the two Incoming tags in my class. If I only put in one of them, then it works fine, but the moment I put more than on Incoming tag in, then it gives the error on startup.

Comment: It is hard to diagnose what is actually happening looking at just the configuration. As I wrote this typically happens if the annotations are not recognized. I suggest you create an issue in the Quarkus repo with a minimal reproducer.